# How can I reset MySQL Community Server to default setting in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ubuntu-22.04

[the result of the command journalctl -xeu mysql.service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5Hzi.png)Please help I am running Ubuntu 22.04
I had MySQL running perfectly before I installed MariaDB for a project and after I uninstalled MariaDB and installed MySQL but the server won't start.

The first Error I got when I type mysql in the terminal

```
"ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)" in 5 steps How can I fix this MySQL error on Ubuntu 22.04?
```

I tried to fix this by deleting the mariaDB files I found in the mysqld directory and editing the file mysqld.sock with the following informations

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[client]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

How do I completely uninstall and restore the MySQL server.

I tried to fix this by deleting the mariaDB files I found in the mysqld directory and editing the file mysqld.sock with the following informations

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[client]
socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

This didn't work and I tried to uninstall and install mysql with the following command.

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt install mysql-server
```

now I got the message during installation.

```
MySQL has been frozen to prevent damage to your system. Please see /etc/mysql/FROZEN for help.
```

Then I ran this set of commands:

1. service mysql start
2. systemctl unmask mysql.service
3. service mysql start
4. journalctl -xeu mysql.service
5. sudo less /var/log/mysql/error.log

I tried to check the error log but there is no error log file
How do I completely uninstall and restore the MySQL server.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to solve the problem using these two lines of command

```
sudo apt remove --purge mysql-\*
sudo apt install mysql-server mysql-client
```

After this, I continued with the MySQL setup and it was a good as new